# TRACE Macro Not Compiled Out Properly in Release Build - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, trace, release-builds

When I do a Release build of my Visual Studio 2008 solution I get a bunch of errors like this:

> error C2059: syntax error : ','

This is how I typically use `TRACE`:

```
TRACE(_T("My error message.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
```

There is also an instance where I use it with 5 parameters.

I thought `TRACE` was suppose to compile out completely for Release builds.  What do I need to do to make it compile out complete?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. What other errors are you getting?

Comment: The error described in the post is the only one I get, a whole bunch of them, once for each time `TRACE` is used.

Comment: is `__WFILE__` defined correctly? you can check by doing a preprocessing pass...

Comment: (1) Do you get the same error if you comment out this line? (2) Where and how is `__WFILE__` defined? It’s not a standard part of VS2008 AFAICT. (3) What if you use `_T(__FILE__)` instead of `__WFILE__`?

Comment: @lijie: In Debug __WFILE__ is defined as `#define __WFILE__ (L ## __FILE__)`.  In Release it is defined as simply `#define __WFILE__`.

Comment: @Nate: Changing `__WFILE__` to `_T(__FILE__)` did the trick.  Thanks!  Post that as your answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of your `__WFILE__` macro is causing the problem. There are two ways to solve this. First, you can define the macro as shown here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.80).aspx

Note they don’t wrap the macro in `#ifdef _DEBUG`, which makes sense since the corresponding `__FILE__` macro is not removed in release mode either.

But that documentation is for VS2005. It’s been removed from newer versions of the documentation. That’s why you may want to do this:

```
_T(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's `__FILE__` as far as I know, not `__WFILE__`. that is why you get that comma error. Since preprocessor is unable to find it.

Second, why do you write the last three parameters in each TRACE? TRACE is a MACRO, right?

So you can define it like this: (also see the define `__WFILE__` macro)

```
#define FULL_TRACE   //define FULL_TRACE here
#define __WFILE__  L##__FILE__ //since __WFILE__ is not a real macro in MCVC++
#define TRACE(msg) FULL_TRACE(msg, ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)
```

Now, you can TRACE like this

```
TRACE("Error in I/O file")
```

And you're done!